# How to calculate the number of specific events per user in dataset in another column?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to create another column in my dataset with number of previous specific events for each user (in my case number of completed levels)

My data looks like:

| event_dttm | user_id | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 1111 | complete_level |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:30.000 | 1111 | start_level |
| 2022-04-07 00:04:44.000 | 1111 | complete_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:15:00.000 | 1111 | start_session |
| 2022-05-28 09:17:28.000 | 1111 | start_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:18:46.000 | 1111 | complete_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:19:39.000 | 1111 | start_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:26:16.000 | 1111 | complete_level |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 1221 | start_session |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:30.000 | 1221 | start_level |
| 2022-04-07 00:04:44.000 | 1221 | complete_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:15:00.000 | 1221 | start_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:16:12.000 | 1221 | complete_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:17:28.000 | 1221 | start_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:18:46.000 | 1221 | complete_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:19:39.000 | 1211 | start_level |
| 2022-05-28 09:26:16.000 | 1221 | complete_level |

Desired result:

| event_dttm | user_id | event_name | completed_levels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 1111 | complete_level | 1 |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:30.000 | 1111 | start_level | 1 |
| 2022-04-07 00:04:44.000 | 1111 | complete_level | 2 |
| 2022-05-28 09:15:00.000 | 1111 | start_session | 2 |
| 2022-05-28 09:17:28.000 | 1111 | start_level | 2 |
| 2022-05-28 09:18:46.000 | 1111 | complete_level | 3 |
| 2022-05-28 09:19:39.000 | 1111 | start_level | 3 |
| 2022-05-28 09:26:16.000 | 1111 | complete_level | 4 |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 1221 | start_session | 0 |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:30.000 | 1221 | start_level | 0 |
| 2022-04-07 00:04:44.000 | 1221 | complete_level | 1 |
| 2022-05-28 09:15:00.000 | 1221 | start_level | 1 |
| 2022-05-28 09:16:12.000 | 1221 | complete_level | 2 |
| 2022-05-28 09:17:28.000 | 1221 | start_level | 2 |
| 2022-05-28 09:18:46.000 | 1221 | complete_level | 3 |
| 2022-05-28 09:19:39.000 | 1211 | start_level | 3 |
| 2022-05-28 09:26:16.000 | 1221 | complete_level | 4 |
| 2022-05-28 09:29:18.000 | 1211 | start_level | 4 |
| 2022-05-28 09:35:16.000 | 1221 | complete_level | 5 |

I tried to create column with 0/1 if event_name = 'complete_level', count cumulative sum per user and then join it to first table, but it return me an error `Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause`.

```
select event_dttm, user_id, event_name, 
sum(completed_level) 
over (partition by event_dttm, user_id order by user_id, event_dttm) as completed_levels
from
(select event_dttm, user_id, event_name 
case
when event_name = 'complete_level' then 1
else 0
end as completed_level
from table)
```

Also I think that there is simpler solution for my task.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select
 *,
 sum(case when event_name = 'complete_level' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by user_id order by event_dttm asc) as completed_cnt
from your_table
```

[image]